# How to remove single quotes from column name of sql query in Java

Tags: java

I am getting a string something like this.

```
'ename' = 'ABC' AND 'esal' > '10000' OR 'dept' != 'HR'
```

I want to add this condition in sql query through Java but before that I need to remove single quotes from column names and this condition should look like below.

```
ename = 'ABC' AND esal > '10000' OR dept != 'HR'
```

How can I do this in Java.

I have written a piece of code below. please suggest if there is any better solution for this.

```
char[] arr = str.toCharArray(); 
for(int i= 0; i< arr.length; i++) { 
   if(arr[i] == '=' || arr[i] == '>') { 
      int temp = i-1; 
      int count = 0; 
      while(count < 2) { 
        if(arr[temp] == '\'') { 
           arr[temp] = '\0'; 
           count++; 
        } 
        temp--; 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I have written a piece of code below. please suggest if there is any better solution for this.

char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
  for(int i= 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] == '=' || arr[i] == '>') {
    int temp = i-1;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 2) {
     if(arr[temp] == '\'') {
      arr[temp] = '\0';
      count++;
     }
     temp--;
    }
   }
  }

Comment: How can you be sure that `'dept'` is a column name and `'HR'` is a string literal? Why cannot they provide you with saner input?

Comment: Why? How does this problem arise? Do you realize that the input is ambiguous? Where is this data coming from? What is the outer problem here?

Answer (score 0):

For simple sql statments like your example, which are only concatenated with `and` and `or` you can try something similar as below. But this will not work with complicated statments if you have for example nested `In` clauses or `subselects`.

```
String query ="'ename' = 'ABC' AND 'esal' > '10000' OR 'dept' != 'HR'";

String andOrRegex = "((?<=(AND|OR))|(?=(AND|OR)))";
String compOperRegex = "((?<=[=\\!<>]+)(?![=\\!<>])|(?<![=\\!<>])(?=[=\\!<>]+))";

String[] splited = query.split(andOrRegex);

String modified = Arrays.stream(splited)
            .map(s -> s.split(compOperRegex))
            .map(arr -> arr.length > 1 ? new String[]{arr[0].replace("'", ""),arr[1],arr[2]} : arr)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(modified);
```

What the above snippet does:

Split the string at `AND` and `OR` but keep the delimeters to get something like this

```
['ename' = 'ABC' , AND,  'esal' > '10000' , OR,  'dept' != 'HR']
```

stream over the array and split at one or more comparison operators `[=\\!<>]+` to produce

```
[['ename' , =,  'ABC' ], [AND], [ 'esal' , >,  '10000' ], [OR], [ 'dept' , !=,  'HR']]
```

Replace the single quotes at the first array element

Flatmap the single arrays and cocatenate them again to a string to get the desired result

```
ename = 'ABC' AND esal > '10000' OR dept != 'HR'
```